# How to set actions/upload-artifact path for a build with dynamic name?

Tags: android, gradle, github-actions

I am defining a CI/CD pipeline for GitHub Actions. I have 2 flavors, production and staging, and every time code is merged in main I want to create build i.e stagingDebug to artifact.

The issue I am facing is the build name is dynamically generated through Gradle. I want to know how I can accommodate dynamic name inside path.

Gradle:

```groovy
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.app"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 22
        versionName "1.7.0.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        def formattedDate = new Date().format('yy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss')
        archivesBaseName = "$applicationId-v$versionCode($versionName)-$formattedDate"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

productFlavors {
        stagging {
            applicationId "com.xyz.app.stagging"
      
            copy {
                from 'src/stagging/'
                include 'google-services.json'
                into '.'
            }
        }
    }
```

Generated file name under:

```
app/build/outputs/apk/stagging/debug/com.xyz.app.stagging-v22(1.7.0.6)-24-02-05 10.10.19-stagging-debug.apk
```

GitHub Action:

```yaml
name: AndroidBuild
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.1

      - name: Set up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v4.0.0
        with:
          distribution: 'adopt'
          java-version: '11'

      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: |
          ./gradlew assembleStaggingDebug

      - name: Upload APK
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4.3.0
        with:
          name: stagging_artifiact
          path: app/build/outputs/apk/stagging/debug/${dynamically named apk}.apk
```

Comment: If there's only one `apk` file is being generated then you can simply omit its name and use wildcard * instead. See [usage](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) and this [example](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact?tab=readme-ov-file#upload-using-a-wildcard-pattern) for more details. Alternatively, you can set the file name as an env var or an output parameter as well and use with appropriate context to set the `path` input param.

Comment: Relevant: [Setting an environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) and [Setting an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use wildcards

Change upload stage like this:

```yaml
- name: Upload APK
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4.3.0
  with:
  name: stagging_artifiact
  path: app/build/outputs/apk/stagging/debug/*.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try
`${{dynamically named apk}}`

Not sure if the extra bracket makes a difference. Worth a go.

Comment: Could you provide more context to your answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).